# laravel 7 csrf token change after login

Tags: laravel, authentication, token, csrf

To assign the items in the shopping cart to the user, I use the CSRF token. however, if the user logs in, a new token is automatically generated and the shopping cart is empty.

how can I prevent a new token from being generated, or where can I query the new and old csrf token to update it in my database?

there is another way to connect the user and the shopping cart?

Comment: are you trying to write a guest shopping cart? I mean, people can add products to their cart without logging in.

Comment: the customer can log in at the checkout so that he does not have to enter his address every time

Comment: are you sure its csrf causing the issue, check if session is being overwritten when loggin in?

Comment: yes the session is overwritten, but how can i prevent that?